# Limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(x^\frac{7}{6}-x^\frac{6}{7}\cdot \ln^2( x) \right)$ using L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(x^\frac{7}{6}-x^\frac{6}{7}\cdot \ln^2( x) \right)$$
I can not decide the limit. I understand that it is necessary to apply L'Hôpital's rule, when there will be a fraction.
But to start, how to make this shot in this example?

Please help me to solve it L'Hospital's rule!

Comment: $ln^2 x$ : $(ln\ x)^2$ or $ln\ x^2 $ ?

Comment: This is $$(lnx)^2$$

Comment: Actually I would have interpreted $\ln^2(x)$ as $\ln\ln x$.

Comment: Look at the task!

Comment: the limit remains the same if we replace $x$ by $x^{42}$ and you will get $x^{49}-42^2x^36ln(x)^2$ which is effectively $+\infty$ because of th comparison between powers, For the question I don't think that there is a theorem saying that :"every limit can be computed using L'Hopital's rule"

Comment: Intuitively, $x^{\epsilon}$ eventually grows "faster" than $\ln^2 x$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, so the left term dominates the right term since its power is larger and the $\ln^2 x$, as $x$ gets sufficiently large, doesn't have an effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to do is a substitution: set $x=t^{42}$, so $x^{6/7}=t^{36}$, $x^{7/6}=t^{49}$ and $\ln x=42\ln t$. Then the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}(t^{49}-t^{36}\cdot 42^2(\ln t)^2)=
\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{49}\left(1-1764\frac{(\ln t)^2}{t^{13}}\right)
$$
Now we have something to which we can apply l’Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(\ln t)^2}{t^{13}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2\ln t}{13t^{13}}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{2}{169t^{13}}=0
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, it is usually necessary to use

Comment: @andre1 I have no problem whatsoever with the late Marquis de l’Hôpital and I let students freely use his theorem, *when it's helpful*.

Comment: But my teacher too principled. He is required to use this rule.

Comment: Didn't you mix up the roles of $t^{49}$ and $t^{36}$ here?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, I'll fix it!

Comment: @andre1 Sorry, I had interchanged two expressions; now it's fixed and, for your satisfaction, l’Hôpital can be applied. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, you are help me.